# How to remove last character of a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have many lines similar to

```
"HHH |**** XYzz| *ABC*hgg|G~GG|G|HJJ|JJJ|          |"

"HHH |**** XYzz| *ABC*hgg|G~GG|G|HJJ|HHH|" 

"HHH |**** XYzz| *ABC*hgg|G~GG|G|HJJ|III|          |"
```

I want to remove last pipe and spaces from such lines which contains extra |

my required output is

```
"HHH |**** XYzz| *ABC*hgg|G~GG|G|HJJ|JJJ|"

"HHH |**** XYzz| *ABC*hgg|G~GG|G|HJJ|HHH|" 

"HHH |**** XYzz| *ABC*hgg|G~GG|G|HJJ|III|"
```

I have tried for 1 string but the problem is this also eliminates the spaces present inside that string.

```
A=  "HHH |**** XYzz| *ABC*hgg|G~GG|G|HJJ|JJJ|          |"
Y=A.split()
print(Y)

final=[]

if Y[-1]=='~':
    ab=Y[:-1]
    cd=''.join(ab)
    print(cd)
else:
    ef=''.join(Y)
    print(ef)
```

Comment: The answer below gives you a better method, but the reason your spaces are lost is your `join` call is on `''` which won't add back the spaces removed by `split()`. Use `' '.join(...)` to add the space back.

Answer (score 3):

use a regex with 1 or more spaces then a pipe then end of line.

```
your_string = re.sub("\s+\|$","",your_string)
```

testing:

```
>>> your_string = "HHH |**** XYzz| *ABC*hgg|G~GG|G|HJJ|JJJ|          |"
>>> re.sub("\s+\|$","",your_string)
'HHH |**** XYzz| *ABC*hgg|G~GG|G|HJJ|JJJ|'
>>> your_string = "HHH |**** XYzz| *ABC*hgg|G~GG|G|HJJ|JJJ|"
>>> re.sub("\s+\|$","",your_string)
'HHH |**** XYzz| *ABC*hgg|G~GG|G|HJJ|JJJ|'
```

Comment: You can use `re.sub("\|\s+\|$", "|", your_string)` to avoid the edge case where the last column is not whitespaces only but has trailing whitespaces.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a regex replacement here:

```py
inp = "HHH |**** XYzz| *ABC*hgg|G~GG|G|HJJ|JJJ|          |"
output = re.sub(r'(?<=\|)\s*\|$', '', inp)
print(output)  # HHH |**** XYzz| *ABC*hgg|G~GG|G|HJJ|JJJ|
```

The regex pattern used here says to match:

```regex
(?<=\|)  assert that last pipe separated column is empty
\s*      match zero or more whitespace characters
\|       match final pipe
$        end of the input
```

The lookbehind `(?<=\|)` ensures that we don't strip away the final pipe for something like this:

```
|ABC|DEF|GHI     |
```

In this case, the spaces are part of the data and the last element is not empty.